# Need to change font color in "difference"

Tags: color, text

Working in Photoshop, I have a background with 3 different colors and needed the text to adjust accordingly, set to "difference" and the text over the black and white portions of the background did as I wanted, but the text over the blue part of the background is orange. Can I change it to be either black or white like the rest of the text? Example in picture.
[image: text difference colors]

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your text into a layer group. (White text only)
2. Set the text layer to difference.
3. Create a "Black and White" adjustment layer above that group
   (not inside the group).
4. In the properties of the adjustment layer, click the button at the
   bottom that applies the adjustment layer to only the object directly
   below in the layer stack (as shown).
5. Configure the black and white adjustment layer as show, with every
   color maxed at 300.
   [image]
   Final Result:
   [image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but I must have done something wrong...

Comment: Are you in RGB  color mode?

Comment: Yes, I am. Do I need to be in CMYK?

Comment: AHA! I didn't have the text in a group layer, fixed! Thanks a ton!!

Comment: RGB color mode is probably necessary. It would be much appreciated if you could mark my answer as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Hue/Saturation adjustment layer, which affects to orange making it black.

[image]

Whitening needs smarter tricks or brute force. The latter means: Have both white and black texts. Add to the upper text layer a layer mask, which kills the wanted areas. An example:

[image]

The layer mask is done by making a color range selection (text layers closed) and then adding a layer mask to the top text layer. The mask forms from the selection.